# How do I use the older version of node.js buildpack?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I've been using Node.js as my runtime within Bluemix for a few weeks now but I saw somewhere that there's a new version of the runtime now live on Bluemix.  I have some changes to my app that need to be pushed but I'm not sure if I'm quite ready to move to the new buildpack version yet.  Is there a way to use the older version of the buildpack while I complete my testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can still use v1.18, as it will be available on Bluemix for a period of time and can be accessed using the CF command below:

```
$ cf push your_app_name -b sdk-for-nodejs_v1-18-20150519-1759
```

Or, you can specify the following in your manifest.yml:

```
buildpack: sdk-for-nodejs_v1-18-20150519-1759
```

All available buildpacks installed on the system can be viewed using the following command:

```
$ cf buildpacks
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about the default version of Node.js moving from 0.10 to 0.12 with the buildpack updates, it is still possible to manually specify the runtime version by setting the following property in your package.json file:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x"
}
```